# onchange not working in table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events

so I am having an issue figuring out why my `onchange` event isn't firing. To start off here is a copy of my table and my JavaScript

Table:

```
<form name="form1" action="submit.php" method='POST'>
    <table border="0" class="signUp">
    <tr><td align="center" class= "signUpfont"> Sign up for FREE </td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" text="First Name" class='signUpinput' id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class='signUpinput' id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class='signUpinput' id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" class='signUpinput' id="email2" name="email2"  placeholder="Re-enter Email"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="password" class='signUpinput' id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
                    <select name="country" onchange="getStates()" style="color: white; background-color: #2B4478;">
        <option value="0">Select State</option>
        <option value="louisiana">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="texas">Texas</option>
        <option value="alabama">Alabama</option>
        <option value="mississippi">Mississippi</option>
    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><select name="school" style="color: white;background-color: #2B4478;">
        <option value="">Select School</option>
    </select></td></tr>

    <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" style="color:white; background-color:#2B4478; width: 100px;margin-left: 52px;"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStates()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        try{
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
           }catch(e)
           {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
               }

        if(xmlhttp)
            {
                var form = document['form1'];
                var country = form['country'].value;

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "getSchools.php?country="+country, true);

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
                {
                    if(this.readyState == 4)
                    {
                        var s = document.createElement('select');
                        s.name = "school";
                        s.style.color = "white";
                        s.style.background = "#2b4478";
                        s.innerHTML = this.responseText;

                        if(form['school'])
                        {
                            form.replaceChild(s, form['school']);

                        }else
                            form.insertBefore(s, form['submit']);
                    }
                }                   

                xmlhttp.send(null)
            }
    }
```

Any pointers to something I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.  If I put both the dropdowns in the same  and start the form in that, the script will work, but I can't get the rest of the table information.

Comment: Maybe put it as onchange="getStates();"

Comment: @msbodetti Thank you for the response, I've tried adding the semicolon and stil having the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Your function is being fired correctly. Try setting a breakpoint on the function in the debugger and see what errors your getting/or if your breakpoint is even being hit.

See http://jsfiddle.net/7VWhx/1/

```
   function getStates()
    {
        console.log('getStates fired');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that getStates() exists when the onchange event fires, i.e. the script which defines it should have already executed before it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "getStates" function is accessible to the HTML at the time of execution.  Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2GbH8/

Fiddle does things a little weird, so I had to assign the function to a global variable:

```
getStates = function getStates() {...}
```

The Fiddle works once it is assigned like that.